# Eu Cookies Law and Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is probably not a technical question but more related to legislation:

In these years European countries are due adjust with eu cookies law (synthetically every web site must inform/asks agreement/and so on to their users about every kind of cookies used by the sites).
Recently we spent some time to analyze possible implementations about informer banner/pop up. Our doubt concerns javascript implementation, for example as suggested here https://www.cookiechoices.org/  with Google collaboration.

These implementations - pure Javascript - should work only if a browser enables  javascript, so what happens if a browser disables javascript? Would this web site outlaw?

Comment: no javascript = no ads or social stuff. This law is only for cookies about storing personal information, tracking and social stuff. So you should not care about javascript disabled I guess

Comment: @Hacketo: this is a gross over-simplification and falls into a common pitfall of assuming that privacy and anonymity are the same thing.

Comment: @symcbean If javascript is disabled, the browser can't store cookies from the JS API, so I guess you don't need to ask users for cookies that will not exists. Cookies about auth / session / shopping cart/... does not need user agreement. Not talking about privacy or anonymity.

Comment: cookies can be also stored from server side. 
We know that technical cookies don't need user agreement but for the eu law the user must be always informed about these.

Comment: I don't believe there is a requirement to provide information about LSOs covered by the consent exception in the EU directive and in UK law.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law and legislation. Consult a lawyer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These implementations - pure Javascript - should work only if a browser enables javascript, so what happens if a browser disables javascript? Would this web site outlaw?

The mechanism used to show agreement is quite simple, explained on the first page and can be implemented by serverside code just as well as in Javascript:

> With each tool, you can customise a notice or statement directed to your visitors and invite your visitors to close the message (using wording of your choice such as "close", "accept" or "I agree"). Users also have the option of clicking a link to another page, such as a page that explains how your site uses cookies (again, you choose the wording for this link text). If users close the message, a cookie will be set to your domain. It is called 'displayCookieConsent' and has the value 'y'.

Simply put an iframe in the div to communicate cookie preferences serverside.

Although your question specifically relates to the tools available from the cookiechoice website, you are no doubt aware that article 5(3) of the ePrivacy directive has much wider scope and conditional context that may negate the need for this kind of consent, or indeed, depending on your application, require the capability to allow and deal with the scenario where the user explicitly explicitly refuses cookies. Hence whether your site would be illegal (which also brings the question of the implementations of the directive in different jurisdictions) is highly dependent on what your site does and how it uses the cookies. (e.g. see [this discussion](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2012/wp194_en.pdf) of exemptions)